# Nightmare Puzzlang translator

Tags: code-golf, grid

## Background

[Puzzlang](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Puzzlang) is a derivative of Brainfuck, where the symbol `X` executes a BF command based on three characters on top of it, and anything else does nothing.

The following is the translation table for Puzzlang, where `X` is the literal X and `.` stands for anything else:

```
 >      <      +      -      .      ,      [      ]

..X    X..    XXX    ...    .X.    X.X    XX.    .XX
 X      X      X      X      X      X      X      X
```

Also, the entire source code wraps around both horizontally and vertically at the translation step. For example, the following code is an infinite loop:

```
XX X
```

since you can view the code like this (the dots are where the wrapped X's would go)

```
... ..
.XX X.
```

and matching with the translation table gives `+[]` for the three X's in order.

**Nightmare Puzzlang** is an evil twin of the regular Puzzlang. In Nightmare Puzzlang, each X translates into a byte based on its eight neighbors. Any non-X characters translate into nothing. The wrapping rule is the same.

Since there is no "official" specification, let's assume that the following pattern (where X denotes the one to translate)

```
abc
dXe
fgh
```

translates to `abcdefgh` in binary (X is one, non-X is zero). Then the following code

```
XX...
X..X.
X..XX
X..XX
X.XX.
```

translates to `4a b4 66 03 56 4b bf d2 6e fd c3 2c 70` in hex, or `J´fVK¿ÒnýÃ,p` as a string. Note that the resulting string will very likely have ASCII unprintables.

## Task

Translate the given Nightmare Puzzlang code into a string.

## Input & output

For input, you can take 2D array of chars, list of strings, or a single string whose lines are delimited by newlines. You can assume that the input is rectangular in shape, i.e. row lengths are equal.

For output, you can give a single string, a list of chars, or a list of charcodes.

## Test Cases

Note that the result must remain the same when any of the dots are replaced with anything else other than the capital X.

```
X (1 row, 1 column)
String: ÿ
Charcode: [255]

X. (1 row, 2 columns)
String: B
Charcode: [66]

X
. (2 rows, 1 column)
String: 
Charcode: [24]

X.
.X
String: ¥¥
Charcode: [165, 165]

X.X
.X.
String: 1Œ¥
Charcode: [49, 140, 165]

X.X
XX.
X.X
String: ÓmÎµv«
Charcode: [211, 109, 206, 181, 118, 171]

X.XX.XXX..XXXX.
String: BkÖkÿÖkÿÿÖ
Charcode: [66, 107, 214, 107, 255, 214, 107, 255, 255, 214]

X.XX.XXX.XXXXX.
XX.X..XX....X..
String: c­R){Ö9Z”JµÆïÖç
Charcode: [99, 173, 82, 41, 123, 214, 8, 24, 57, 90, 148, 74, 181, 198, 239, 214, 231]

X
X
X
.
.
X
.
X
X
.
X
String: ÿÿøø
Charcode: [255, 255, 248, 24, 31, 248, 31]

XX
X.
XX
.X
.X
XX
..
XX
XX
..
.X
String: º]ç]ºâG¸Xøø
Charcode: [186, 93, 231, 93, 186, 226, 71, 184, 88, 31, 31, 248, 248, 7]

XX XXX XX  XX
X  X X X X X 
X  X X X X XX
X  X X X X X 
XX XXX XX  XX
             
XXX XXX X  XX
X   X X X  X 
X X X X X  XX
X X X X X  X 
XXX XXX XX X 
(11 rows, 13 columns, no extra padding, result has two newlines)
zôª}òªuJ½æbÂb‚cRBBBBJ½ÇCFCDcXH¸PH°H¸

æbÂBcRBBBJ½ÃFCFCbO¾UO¾UN”C
Charcode: [122, 244, 170, 125, 242, 170, 117, 74, 189, 230, 98, 194, 98, 130, 99, 82, 66, 66, 66, 66, 74, 189, 199, 67, 70, 67, 68, 99, 88, 144, 72, 184, 80, 72, 176, 72, 184, 26, 28, 16, 10, 29, 18, 2, 10, 29, 230, 98, 194, 66, 99, 82, 2, 66, 66, 66, 74, 189, 195, 70, 67, 70, 67, 98, 79, 190, 85, 79, 190, 85, 78, 148, 67]
```

## Rules

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest submission in bytes wins.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 57 bytes

```apl
¯1~⍨,1↓∘⍉∘⌽⍣4⊢{2 2⌷⍵:2⊥(~¯9↑5↑1)/,⍵⋄¯1}⌺3 3⊢⍉∘(¯1∘↑⍪⊢⍪1∘↑)⍣2⊢'X'=⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU9Na8JAEL37K/YWBbtlV3Noof9jroLoRajXIuYkMbXZghShZ4tQcvGiCAUv/pT5I3F2dvNJN5nZee/NvExG89nD@G00e53mmKwn@e2oIjS/fYXxFybfaN5tTq9ofoa42S@00Jhe0JyfNW4O3eh2fMJ4G1Ko3mOfePxYkccS07@BGNCEc@gSZ43iLZqM2czjHjmT1T6A4AU/d3aLfNJRQqE5EdexteZaWqALQQSMycEqhKCCrIJsEsBtIL2nCp0p2BekTY0JR4OjeZqbJB1K3Ggy3qMI6QNqd1UXzsw6R7e1Tw6WQgVrPwYCOIRwPXSXTwv/q7fmRf2w7hsqfz9c@EOJoYUb8/y9Ow)

A full program which takes a binary matrix through STDIN, returns an array of codepoints.

### Explanation

`x¯1~⍨,1↓∘⍉∘⌽⍣4⊢{2 2⌷⍵:2⊥(~¯9↑5↑1)/,⍵⋄¯1}⌺3 3⊢⍉∘(¯1∘↑⍪⊢⍪1∘↑)⍣2⊢'X'=⎕`

`⎕` take input

`'X'=`  boolean matrix where 'X's are 1s

`⍉∘(...)⍣2⊢` do the following twice:

`¯1∘↑⍪⊢⍪1∘↑` pad each row with its wraparound on both sides

`⍉∘` and transpose

`{...}⌺3 3⊢` then, do the following for each 3x3 window:

`2 2⌷⍵:` if the middle element is 1:

`2⊥(~¯9↑5↑1)/,⍵` decode the rest of the window as binary

`⋄¯1` Otherwise, return ¯1.

`⍣4⊢` Do the following 4 times:

`1↓∘⍉∘⌽` rotate 90°, drop first row (remove the border cells)

`,` flatten into a simple array

`¯1~⍨` remove all ¯1s

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>166</s> <s>162</s> 161 bytes

```
lambda p,r=range:[chr(int(''.join(str(+([n*2for n in p+p][y+i//3-1][x+i%3-1]=='X'))for i in r(9)if i-4),2))for y in r(len(p))for x in r(len(p[0]))if'X'==p[y][x]]
```

Takes as input a list of strings and returns a character array.

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##hVDRboIwFH33K25YlraCuOleZtKnfcJemiAPTIp20dIUjBLjt7NCGVbTbAWaw7nnnN5e1dS7Ui7bgq7bfXb4yjNQkaY6k1u@SjY7jYWsMULxdykkrmqNQ5zI6aIoNUgQElSo0qQJxXy@nL2myTkUzx2gFDFESCcTnUzjdyIKELM3Ei0s31h@zyVWljk7TPKSEuMwKZSqpDHJadrmvICaVzWe7oXkFVlNwCylux4tFUHFFUVriSLgMqcIEUdTIMCXLt7ar6DLk7HcqO7UK2zK/fEgKzJ4M1mduAYKxeCDJ9C8PmpZQQabXaYh0zpr7g76rA3YruASBHZ2NoVcHxr6MPZNmXOjTEqdY0lgnK21pFdzGzKZ9BcPWEB@UXyDQdSHQhC75ZF0TWwtAwjHimu4xTDHze7t3cvibrv3Wp5Z3snptbFZZvM07EOxB7E/OX91PM0Rur25A/JAV@C1@QXuuBiw/gNwbeZvfLzsv1pvLrjL0Q7ixx6G0Pse2MgyL@vJ7Tsj7Q8)

Ungolfed (sorta):

```
def f(p):
    chars = []
    for y in range(len(p)):
        for x in range(len(p[0])):
            if p[y][x] != 'X':
                continue
            bits = []
            for i in range(9):
                if i == 4:
                    continue
                bit_x = x + i%3 - 1
                bit_y = y + i//3 - 1
                char_at_cell = [n*2for n in p+p][bit_y][bit_x]
                bit = str(+(char_at_cell=='X'))
                bits.append(bit)
            char_code = int(''.join(bits), 2)
            chars.append(chr(char_code))
    return chars
```

Edit: made shorter by 5 bytes thanks to Jo King and Jonathan Frech

Comment: Since the function ins't recursive, you don't need to assign the lambda. [162 bytes](https://tio.run/##hVDRboMgFH3vV9y5LEB1bmv3siY87RP2QmJ9cIoti0WDNq1p@u0diLG0IRsquZ57zrkHmr7b1nJ5Ken6UmW77yKDJlJUZXLDV0m@VVjIDiMU/9RC4rZTOMSJnC/KWoEEIaEJmzTpQ/Hysnx@S5NjKJ5MQSliiBBDE4am8AcRJYgH@k6ihW30tlFxiRuLHB0keU2JlmgbSpuk19Zpeil4CR1vOzyvhOQtWc1Ar0aZkBaKoOUNRWuJIuCyoAgRh1MiwCdjb@VnUPVBS66QmXqGvK72O9mSUZvJ9sAVUChHHTyC4t1eyRYyyLeZgkyprL8Z9NXpYrOCUxDYy7Mu5HwX6FPL87rgmpnUqsCSwHS5VpKe9WnIbDYcPGAxMy@LzcbigNzjzOLRMAUCgxhurJfervwrw1PFnor9ifm70zSH6Ga7irylS/DK/ITYHQxs@ABcmf6bHi/6L9frC@5yuCP5PsNoepuBTSjzoh7fIRm5/AI)

Comment: oh nice, didn't know that you could remove that, cheers. Just writing up the ungolfed version and will add in your changes

Comment: Note that the slash's orientation matters. You used `/` -- a slash -- to continue a line in C-style, use a backslash: `\ `.

Comment: You can golf your one `!=` to a `-`.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 159 bytes

Takes input as a 2D array of characters. Returns an array of character codes.

```javascript
f=M=>M.map((r,y)=>r.map((v,x)=>v>f&&o.push([...'22211000'].map((k,j)=>s|=(M[(y+h+~-k)%h][(x+w+~-'21020'[j%5])%w]>f)<<j,h=M.length,w=M[s=0].length)|s)),o=[])&&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVHNjoMgGLz7FFwsEClBk70V38A7CeFgulrXumq0q23S7Ku7/m23dEtVxHzzMc4MkIZNWO@rj/K0zYv3qOtiHnA/oJ9hiVBFLpj71QQacu5B48ebTUHLrzpBklIKPc9zXcYYVBPtSNKeVl85CiS6OInzvT1iO1ESnZ22B9BzmcegTO03he1W@THe7VKS8IBmUX44JaTlgaw5UzPG1xpjUnCpcO/c7Yu8LrKIZsUBxUhaAIwxBFSWwtgyLdOFdajIb02Xpf64i76a8mIMjS40K7HCa3gFHT4rnCaymMn3rqNEXw/F@nMz1dRQixX9F5yXsTQNfXcPt/cc6DSjgJm2eFkCiHECoCv2@DYM/VV8gz69fzT@/MP/PLP4Yx5x6wtDHzzTn3IOR9P9AA)

#### Commented

```javascript
f = M =>                        // f = main function taking the input matrix
                                //     it is named because we are later using '>f'
  M.map((r, y) =>               // for each row r[] at position y in M[]:
    r.map((v, x) =>             //   for each value v at position x in r[]:
      v > f &&                  //     ignore this cell if v is not equal to 'X'
      o.push(                   //     otherwise, push a new value in o[]:
        [...'22211000']         //       iterate over dy values (+1)
        .map((k, j) =>          //       for each value k at position j in this array:
          s |= (                //         update s:
            M[(y + h +          //           compute the row
              ~-k)              //           by adding dy = k - 1
              % h]              //           and applying a modulo h
            [(x + w +           //           compute the column
              ~-'21020'[j % 5]) //           by adding dx = [2,1,0,2,0,2,1,0][j] - 1
              % w]              //           and applying a modulo w
            > f                 //           test whether this cell is a 'X'
          ) << j,               //         and set the corresponding bit in s if it is
          h = M.length,         //         initialize h = matrix height
          w = M[s = 0].length   //         initialize w = matrix width and s = bitmask
        ) | s                   //       end of map() over dy; yield s
      )                         //     end of push()
    ),                          //   end of map over r[]
    o = []                      //   initialize o = output array
  ) && o                        // end of map over M[]; return o
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
=”Xµ-r1p`ẸƇ+ⱮŒṪœịµḄ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of the lines and yields a list of code-points.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT0Awv9qZWxsef//PeKAnVjCtS1yMXBg4bq4xocr4rGuxZLhuarFk@G7i8K14biE////WydYLlgnCiwnLlguJwpd)**

#### How?

```
=”Xµ-r1p`ẸƇ+ⱮŒṪœịµḄ - Link: lines
 ”X                 - character = 'X'
=                   - equals? -> binary matrix from lines with X:1 and .:0
   µ             µ  - monadic chain - f(v=that):
    -               -   -1
      1             -   1
     r              -   inclusive range = [-1, 0, 1]
        `           -   use as both arguments of:
       p            -     Cartesian product
                               = [[-1,-1],[-1,0],[-1,1],[0,-1],[0,0],[0,1],[1,-1],[1,0],[1,1]]
          Ƈ         -   keep those for which:
         Ẹ          -     any? = [[-1,-1],[-1,0],[-1,1],[0,-1],[0,1],[1,-1],[1,0],[1,1]]
             ŒṪ     -   multidimensional truthy indices (v)
            Ɱ       -   map across these with:
           +        -     add
               œị   -   index into (v)
                  Ḅ - convert from binary
```